# Domain Driven Design Windows Azure Web Job

Tags: c#, azure, domain-driven-design

Certain behaviors of my domain model qualifies to be delegated to Azure WebJob. If I continue to use same domain model class across Website & Web Job,
it seems like violating separation of concerns. There will be tight coupling between two different processes.

> Should  a background process, Web Job in this case, always have its dedicated Domain Model & behaviors exposed by this should only be consumed by one process?

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly, then you are basically decoupling your  web-role and introducing a web-job for some sort of background/repeated processing maybe. This doesn't seem to be violating the SoC. It is actually a good practice to keep them separate so that the application splits the work between components.

Answer (score 4):

If your domain model is free of any dependencies to the environment (which it should be), then I don't see a problem with that.

**On the contrary: Using the same domain model within a bounded context is preferable, because you are able to capture the business rules in one place.** Like this, you are sure you don't run into impedance mismatch problems between two models.

If you are using domain events, you already have a basis for the communication with the web job. This is exactly what we've been doing for over a year, and it works great:

- Web apps publish domain events to an Azure Storage Queue
- The web job receives them and performs the background processing **on the same model**

So all you need to do is create two separate application / service layers (one for the web application, one for the background worker) and make sure all domain logic is in a reusable library.

Comment: Thanks, glad to know that same DDD model has been used in your setup for over a year & it is working good.

Comment: I have done WebRole & Worker Role setup in my previous project without DDD. Worker role had dedicated class library to encapsulate the business logic. That kind of setup may be better for faster learning curve, your thoughts please?